# PHP/MySQL Login System not checking password

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to follow along with a tutorial for creating a login system for a website but some of the code isn't running. Signing up works fine and I can see the entries in my database, but logging in fails even if I have the correct details. Here is my **login.php** code:

```
    <?php 

        // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
        require("common.php"); 

        // This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the 
        // login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here
        // to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form.
        $submitted_username = ''; 

        // This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted 
        // If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
        if(!empty($_POST)) 
        { 
            // This query retrieves the user's information from the database using 
            // their username. 
            $query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt, email FROM users WHERE username = :username"; 

            // The parameter values 
            $query_params = array( 
                ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
            ); 

            try 
            { 
                // Execute the query against the database 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex) 
            { 
                // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
                // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
                die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
            } 

            // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not.
            // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
            // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
            $login_ok = false; 

            // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username 
            // they entered is not registered. 
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

            if($row) 
            { 
                // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
                // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
                // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database.
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
                for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
                { 
                    print("Checking password");
                    $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
                } 

                if($check_password === $row['password']) 
                { 
                    // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                    $login_ok = true; 
                } 
            } 

            // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
            // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again
            if($login_ok) 
            { 
                // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by 
                // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is 
                // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values 
                // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these 
                // sensitive values first. 
                unset($row['salt']); 
                unset($row['password']); 

                // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
                // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
                // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
                // the user's details. 
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

                // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
                header("Location: secret.html"); 
                die("Redirecting to: secret.html"); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                // Tell the user they failed 
                //print("Login Failed."); 

                // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new 
                // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should 
                // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them 
                // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information: 
                // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack 
                $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            } 
        } 

    ?> 
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form> 
    <a href="signup.php">Register</a>
```

Here is my **register.php** code:

```
<?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. 
            die("Please enter a username."); 
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die("Please enter a password."); 
        } 

        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
        } 

        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this. 
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This username is already in use"); 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This email address is already registered"); 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email 
            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read. 
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk). 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

?> 
<h1>Register</h1> 
<form action="signup.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    E-Mail:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
</form>
```

I have managed to narrow the problem down to:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(); 

if($row) 
{ 
    // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
    // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
    // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database.
    $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        print("Checking password");
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
    } 

    if($check_password === $row['password']) 
    { 
       // If they do, then we flip this to true 
       $login_ok = true; 
    } 
}
```

as the "print("checking password");" never happens. Can anyone spot a problem in the code? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: did you get any errors ?

Comment: $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']);          At this point check, if you get the values from login form by displaying this 2 variables.    $_POST['password']    and   $row['salt']

Comment: @Arjun No, I didn't get any errors

Answer (score 0):

I realised what my problem was... I was attempting to login with the email instead of the username! Thank you all for your help.